# Lining up the bottom of divs

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that only have the border-bottom, and a div in the middle, but bottom of the div in the middle doesn't line up with the 2 divs for some reason. How do I fix this?

```css
body {
        font-size: 0;
}
#line1 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
}
#line2 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
}
#box {
 font-size: 18px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'line1'></div>
<div id = "box"> box </div>
<div id = 'line2'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#line2 {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
width: 25%;
}

#line1 {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css style property:

```
#line1, #line2, #box {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for style use this:

```
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    #line1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
    }
    #line2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
    }
    #box {
        font-size: 18px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

for html add space in line1 & line2

```
<body>
<div id = 'line1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id = "box"> box </div>
<div id = 'line2'>&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```